# Angular - Do i need to use promises for each $http call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `$http` to make various gets and posts to my API however I want to ask should i use a 'deferred/promise' approach or is a simple return ok?

What's the best practice/most stable way?

So - code form:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
            var theReq = {
             method: 'POST',
             url: API + '/class',
             data: {
               option: option
             }
};

$http(theReq)
            .then(function(data){
              deferred.resolve(data);
})

return deferred.promise;
```

Versus:

```
return $http.post(API + '/class', {
      option: option
})
```

Comment: Use latter method, first one is just nonsense

Comment: This is an antipattern. In the above code you are unwrapping a promise only to return another promise. In the below you are just returning the promise. The later is correct. There are plenty of examples on the web that incorreclty prescribe using the above antipattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular does the Promise abstraction for you. Why write 20 lines of code when you only need 3 and let Angular deal with the deferring process ?

Go for the second solution

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - case closed :-)